# GPOs for User Configuration are not overrided

Tags: windows, active-directory, dns, gpo

I've a two GPOs on my domain -> "**Default Domain Policy**" and "**GPO - Diretoria**". **Default Domain Policy** is configured to set proxy settings on all IE browser of the clients (*User Config > Policies > Windows Settings > Internet Explorer Maintenance > Connection > Proxy Settings*). Here are the detailed config used:

```
Internet Explorer Connection
----------------------------
    HTTP Proxy Server:   192.168.100.1:3128
    Secure Proxy Server: 192.168.100.1:3128
    FTP Proxy Server:    192.168.100.1:3128
    Gopher Proxy Server: 192.168.100.1:3128
    Socks Proxy Server:  192.168.100.1:3128
    Auto Config Enable:  No
    Enable Proxy:        Yes
    Use same Proxy:      Yes
```

In the other GPO (**GPO - Diretoria**) the proxy settings are **not configured**. The "Enable proxy settings" check box are disabled in Proxy Settings window. This GPO are linked to an OU called **Diretoria**. Inside this OU, there are 3 computers. When I exec a gpupdate (even gpupdate /force) in any of the 3 computers, the proxy settings still setted as configured in Default Domain Policy!

Then, I´ve performed various tests only with User Configuration Settings and, I´ve noticed (by running *gpresult /z*) that **any** User Configuration Setting setted on Default Domain Policy GPO **cannot be replaced by the "GPO - Diretoria" User Configuration Settings**! BUT, the *Computer Configuration Settings* are replaced perfectly!

```
COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
    CN=MARCOS-SUPVM,OU=Diretoria,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=br
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 5/16/2011 at 5:31:36 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      DC4.internal.domain.com.br
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        internal
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        GPO - Diretoria
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)
.
.
.
.

USER SETTINGS
--------------
    CN=Administrador,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=br
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 5/16/2011 at 5:31:39 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      DC4.internal.domain.com.br
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        INTERNAL
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Default Domain Policy  <-- SEE HERE??? "GPO - Diretoria" ARE NOT PROCESSED!

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)
```

**Why?**

Comment: Better for you to push your question to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) or [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing user policy and computer policy, the policy you setup is applicable to users in an OU not to computer. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The user configuration from `GPO - Diretoria` won't be applied because your user object `CN=Administrador,CN=Users,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=br` is not under "Diretoria" OU.

The computer configuration from `GPO - Diretora` is applied because your computer object 
`CN=MARCOS-SUPVM,OU=Diretoria,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=br` is inside "Directoria" OU

Try moving your administrator user object to OU=Diretoria.  Then, you will see user configuration being applied as well.

Comment: Ok Harvey, thank you! I´ve done what do you sugested (but with another user) and the policy doesn´t excluded proxy settings. 

    CN=teste,OU=Diretoria,DC=domain,DC=suntech,DC=com,DC=br
    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        GPO - Diretoria
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)